# Highlight a line in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textrange

I'm trying to highlight a line in my RichTextBox. My attempt was to get the line's position in the text and then create a TextRange representing `text.Substring(offset, word.Length)`. But somehow the RichTextBox only highlights the last 2 characters of the previous line and some characters of the actual line or just parts of the actual line. My current approach is this one:

```
    public void SelectLine(string text)
    {
        int i = new TextRange(editor.Document.ContentStart, editor.Document.ContentEnd).Text.IndexOf(text);
        TextPointer start = editor.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(i);
        TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(text.Length);

        TextRange r = new TextRange(start, end);

        if (r != null)
        {
            r.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
            r.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
        }
    }
```

And this is how it looks like when I try to select the second line:

[image]

Do you have any idea, why this is happening?

**EDIT:** 
My current approach includes a WPF RichTextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot, I finally came around with this solution. I iterate through the document's blocks whilst counting to the given line. 
I don't care, whether the whole paragraph or just the line is highlighted, because I wrote a small code editor, which should show the error and highlight it in the given source. This is my highlighting code:

```
    public void SelectLine(int line)
    {
        int c = 0;
        TextRange r;

        foreach (var item in editor.Document.Blocks)
        {
            if (line == c)
            {
                r = new TextRange(item.ContentStart, item.ContentEnd);
                if (r.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                r.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
                r.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
                return;
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
```

It iterates through the document's blocks and checks, whether the given block is empty. If so, then the next block will be looked into.

Answer (score 0):

after researching a lot, i found a solution, here all you need!

```
 TextRange Mytextrange2;
 private void Selectline(int line)
    {
        // STEP1: set CaretPosition to fist position of richtextbox (Vietnamese: đưa Carretposition về vị trí đầu của richtextbox)
        TextPointer resetpos = richTextBox.Document.ContentStart;   
        richTextBox.CaretPosition = resetpos;

        // STEP2: get start Position of your line and get startpos of your line +1 (mean end positon of your need line) (Vietnammes: Lấy vị trí đầu và cuối của line)
        TextPointer startPos = richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(line);
        TextPointer endPos = richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(line + 1);

        // STEP3: return if Error
        if (startPos == null) return;
        if (endPos == null) return;

        // STEP4: Clear properties of your previous line (i'm highlighting line by line of richtextbox, so i need to clear properties of previous line before apply new properties to next line)
// Xóa các thuộc tính áp dụng cho dòng trước, vì tôi bôi đen từng dòng trong richtextbox nên khi bôi đen dòng này tôi sẽ bỏ bôi đen dòng trước kia đi
        if (line != 0) // in this case, i clear properties when line != 0, ofcoursce you can change it (trong trường hợp dòng 0, tôi không xóa dòng trước vì trước nó không có dòng nào cả)
        {
            Mytextrange2.ClearAllProperties(); 
            //Mytextrange2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty,Brushes.DarkGray);
            Mytextrange2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkGray);
        }

        // STEP5: Select new textrang and apply new properties to your new line // Dùng textrange để chọn dòng cần bôi đen, sau đó add các thuộc tính vào
        Mytextrange2.Select(startPos, endPos); // select range of text to apply new properties
        Mytextrange2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);  
        Mytextrange2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.DarkGray);
        Mytextrange2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);

        // STEP6: scroll richtextbox to next 14th line to make reasonable view (if imposible). // scroll đến 14 dòng sau dòng được chọn, để dòng được chọn ở giữa khung màn hình, bạn có thể chọn dòng khác
        richTextBox.CaretPosition = startPos; // Set CaretPosition to selected line
        startPos = richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(14); //(find position of next 14th line to scroll ) Change value 14 to have more reasonable view
        if (startPos != null)  richTextBox.CaretPosition = startPos;   // Set caretposition to position of next 14 lines
        richTextBox.Focus();   // scroll richtextbox to caretposition
    }
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Mytextrange2 là biến toàn cục muốn dùng để thực hiện xóa properties của dòng trước, nên tôi phải khởi tạo ở 1 chỗ khác ngoài hàm Selectline
// Initialize Mytextrang2
        Mytextrange2 = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    }
```